# how to vectorize this function

Tags: performance, vectorization, mesh

The following code works, but I would like to create Z by vectorization. How to achieve that?

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import sqrt
from math import fsum    
points = np.array([[0,0],\
                   [5,-1],\
                   [4,6],\
                   [1,3]])
d = lambda x: fsum([sqrt((x[0]-z[0])**2 + (x[1]-z[1])**2) for z in points])
x = np.linspace(min(points[:,0]),max(points[:,0]),100)
y = np.linspace(min(points[:,1]),max(points[:,1]),100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = np.zeros(np.shape(X))
for (i,j),_ in np.ndenumerate(Z):
    Z[i,j] = d([X[i,j],Y[i,j]])
#Z=d([X,Y])  #this fails
```

Comment: works like a charm. though I managed to understand the code, it seems very hard to cultivate the skill organically into my programming. any tutorial on the topic with more details and intuitives?

Comment: Go through the broadcasting docs and a simple google on `numpy broadcasting` gives a lot of good resources.

Comment: got it. in case I use np.mgrid() then the Z shall be created with x[:,None,None] and y[:,None]. a cool trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can leverage [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to work directly with the `1D` versions and thus be more memory efficient and give ourselves a vectorized one-liner, like so -

```
Z = np.sqrt((x[:,None] - points[:,0])**2 + (y[:,None,None] - points[:,1])**2).sum(2)
```

Timings on posted sample data -

```
In [80]: %%timeit
    ...: X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
    ...: Z = np.zeros(np.shape(X))
    ...: for (i,j),_ in np.ndenumerate(Z):
    ...:     Z[i,j] = d([X[i,j],Y[i,j]])
10 loops, best of 3: 101 ms per loop

In [81]: %timeit ((x[:,None] - points[:,0])**2 + (y[:,None,None] - points[:,1])**2).sum(2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 246 µs per loop
```

**`400x`** speedup there!